# how to return from task and mark task as being 'up-to-date'

Tags: gradle

I would like to programmatically tell gradle to return from a task, for example:

```
task ('SetupLibs') << {

    if (sometest)
       // how to tell gradle to return from this task 
       // because it is up-to-date 

    ...
}
```

Is this possible in groovy?  how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`upToDateWhen(){...}`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html#upToDateWhen(org.gradle.api.specs.Spec))

for example:

```
task foo() << {
  outputs.upToDateWhen {
    if (sometest) return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider simply skipping the task, assuming you truly don't want it to do anything https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:skipping_tasks